# Deshabilitar un campo tipo text de formulario reactivo

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo un problema el cual por medio de una función detecto el valor de un select y se habilita ciertos campos y se habilita otros y viceversa, antes de usar formulario reactivo menejaba los ngmodel y sin problemas, ahora con el form reactivo tengo este detalle solo con los campos tipo texto, tengo otros 2 selectores que si obedece estos cambios.

Espero me puedan ayudar o guiar del problema:

```js
onchangeTipoAsesor() {
    console.log(this.FormularioAsesor.value.tipo)
    if (this.FormularioAsesor.value.tipo === 'I') {
      this.bandTipoAsesor = true;
      this.FormularioAsesor.value.empleado = this.FormularioAsesor.value.empleado;
      this.FormularioAsesor.value.opciones_asesor = this.FormularioAsesor.value.opciones_asesor;
      this.FormularioAsesor.value.nombre = '';
      this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_paterno = '';
      this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_materno = '';
    } 
    if (this.FormularioAsesor.value.tipo === 'E') {
      this.bandTipoAsesor = false;
      this.FormularioAsesor.value.empleado = 0;
      this.FormularioAsesor.value.opciones_asesor = 0;
      this.FormularioAsesor.value.nombre = this.FormularioAsesor.value.nombre;
      this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_paterno = this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_paterno;
      this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_materno = this.FormularioAsesor.value.apellido_materno;
    } 
  }
```

**html:** El campo tipo asesor tiene maneja dos valores I y E, cuando inicializa como está en I los campos nombre y apellidos deben estar deshabilitados y opciones asesor y empleado habilitado y cuando se elija Externos[E] se deshabilita opciones, empleado y se debe de habilitar nombre y apellidos, pero solo funciona con los selectores de empleado y no el input tipo texto.

```html
<form [formGroup]="FormularioAsesor" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid grid">
        <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
            <label class="font-bold">Tipo de asesor</label>
            <p-dropdown [options]="select_tipo_asesor" formControlName="tipo" optionLabel="nombre" optionValue="value" placeholder="Selecciona un tipo" (onChange)="onchangeTipoAsesor()"></p-dropdown>
        </div>
        <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
            <label class="font-bold">Opciones de asesor interno</label>
            <p-dropdown [options]="select_opciones_asesor_interno" formControlName="opciones_asesor" optionLabel="nombre" optionValue="value" [disabled]="!bandTipoAsesor" placeholder="Selecciona el tipo de asesor"></p-dropdown>  
        </div>
        <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
            <label class="font-bold">Título</label>
            <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="titulo" class="capitalize" placeholder="Ingrese un título"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
            <label class="font-bold">Empleado</label>
            <p-dropdown [options]="SelectListaAsesoresInternos" formControlName="empleado" optionLabel="asesor" [filter]="true" filterBy="nombre" [showClear]="true"
                placeholder="Seleccione empleado" optionValue="id_colaborador" appendTo="body" [disabled]="!bandTipoAsesor">
                <ng-template let-colaborador pTemplate="item">
                    <div class="flex align-items-center">
                        <span>{{colaborador.nombre}} {{colaborador.apellido_paterno}} {{colaborador.apellido_materno}} </span>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </p-dropdown>
        </div>
        <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
            <label class="font-bold">Nombre(s)</label>
            <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="nombre" [disabled]="bandTipoAsesor" class="capitalize"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
            <label class="font-bold">Apellido paterno</label>
            <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="apellido_paterno" [disabled]="bandTipoAsesor" class="capitalize"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

**Estructura de los campos:**

```js
initForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      //institucion: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      institucion: ['', [Validators.required]],
      tipo: ['', [Validators.required]],
      opciones_asesor: ['', [Validators.required]],
      titulo: ['', [Validators.required]],
      empleado: ['', [Validators.required]],
      nombre: [''],
      apellido_paterno: [''],
      apellido_materno: [''],
      telefono: ['', [Validators.required]],
      extension: ['', [Validators.required]],
      correo: ['', [Validators.required]],
      cargo: ['', [Validators.required]],
      profesion: ['', [Validators.required]],
      nivel_academico: ['', [Validators.required]],
      datos_curriculares: ['', [Validators.required]],
      validar_asesor: [''],
      comentarios: ['']
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo programaticamente

```
this.form.controls['nombre'].disable();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo por responder, me funciono mucho.